# how to pass value to controller from view in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

hello folks I'm working on Laravel 5.2 and there I got stuck in a mess.
Actually I want to pass book_id to controller from hyperlink so that whenever use clicks on the link on the basis of book_id controller will return the description of selected book. How to do this?

View

```
<a href="{{url('bookdetail/'.$value->book_id)}}" class="title" >{{$value->book_name}}</a><br>
```

Controller

```
public function viewbook($id)
{
    $book_detail= DB::select('select * from book_master where book_id=?',[$id]);
    return view('book_detail',['bookdetail'=>$book_detail]);
}
```

Routes

```
Route::any('/bookdetail/{id}','BookDetailsController@viewbook');
```

Also I want to know who to create route for that hyperlink that will pass the book_id to viewbook method

Comment: so where is the problem?

Comment: it returns 
Method App\Http\Controllers\BookDetailsController::viewbook() does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops pity me I only need to add a route into routes.php

```
Route::any('/bookdetail','BookDetailsController@viewbook');
```

Now it's working fine for me!

Answer (score 0):

it should look like:

**BookDetailsController** controller:

```
class BookDetailsController extends Controller {
  public function viewbook($id) {

     $book_detail = DB::table('book_master')
                    ->where('book_id',$id)
                    ->first();

     return view('book_detail',['bookdetail'=>$book_detail]);

  }
}
```

Routes are ok, then in you view you can access to book detail via `{{$bookdetail->fieldName}}`

I hope you get it right.

Comment: nope actually I was right and I only need to add a new route without any parameter now it's working fine thanks btw :)

Comment: @BhavikBamania no problem, but anyway you should use query builder instead of raw expressions (when dealing with easy queries).

Comment: yeah noted will use query builder :)